# <picture> element srcset order importance

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, srcset

Does the source order that you add the `<source>` elements matter? I'm going to be adding multiple file formats and using the type attribute for browser support. So if there isn't a `media` tag to direct the browser. How does it choose a source tag to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Very much like it does when using the sizes algorithm, the browser goes over the list of sources and picks the first one that matches. A match can happen based on both media and type attributes.

Quote is from from [Native responsive images](https://dev.opera.com/articles/native-responsive-images/)

Link to specification which I sometimes find hard to read and get direct answer: [select-an-image-source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#select-an-image-source)