# how to use html picture element?

Tags: html

So I'm trying to display multiple images using the picture tag and whatever I do, the pictures I'm trying to display doesn't seem to appear at all, I don't know what's the problem so I don't know how to fix it.

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="pic">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="images/gallery-01.png">
                    <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="images/gallery-02.png">
                    <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="images/gallery-03.jpg">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your `media=` attributes have a few closing parentheses `)` missing.

Comment: Try `<img src=“url”>`. Also, it doesn’t look like you have closed your parentheses.

Comment: thank you for the help but I added the missing parentheses, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### `<img>` element is required, `<source>` is optional

Your snippet doesn't have any `<img>` tag, which is required. `<source>` elements are optional, which *might* occupy the space presented in `<img>`

Accodring to [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture):

> The `<picture>` HTML element contains zero or more `<source>` elements and one `<img>` element to offer alternative versions of an image for different display/device scenarios.
>
> The browser will consider each child `<source>` element and choose the best match among them. If no matches are found—or the browser doesn't support the `<picture>` element—the URL of the `<img>` element's src attribute is selected. The selected image is then presented in the space occupied by the `<img>` element.

See the updated snippet below. The only change here (except the `picsum.photos` placeholder images) is the addition of `<img>` tage. In this example, the `/300` image will be shown by default, but if/when the browser supports the `<picture>` element and certain media query matches a particular `<source>` image will replace the default image.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="https://picsum.photos/200">
      <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="https://picsum.photos/400">
      <source media="(min-width: 1100px)" srcset="https://picsum.photos/600">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but i have another question.. 
is the order of the order of the source tags important, I mean could i use 
min-width: 1100px;
min-width: 900px;
min-width: 600px;

Comment: Yes, the order of `source` elements matter. See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644823/picture-element-srcset-order-importance) and its linked article [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/native-responsive-images/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you %100 sure that your `srcset= "images/gallery-01.png"` leads to the correct image?
If that's not the problem then I would recommend trying `<img src="images/gallery-01.png">`. Here's the full code,

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="pic">
                <picture>
                    <img alt="Image1" src="images/gallery-01.png">
                    <img alt="Image2" src="images/gallery-02.png">
                    <img alt="Image3" src="images/gallery-03.jpg">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: While I agree that OP needs to ensure the image file path, I'm afraid your code snippet isn't in correct syntax for `<picture>` element. It requires one `<img>` tag as a default fallback, and can have optional `<source>` elements to provide alternative versions of an image per various scenarios (see [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) for reference). Including multiple `<img>` elements without any `<source>` doesn't help solve the issue.